# spring integration sftp: how to trigger the download action manually and do other things after download finish?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-batch

I'm using the spring batch + spring integration sftp on my project.
I don't want the downloading triggered on app startup. I want the download process be triggered in step1 and go on step2 AFTER all the files download to local,  not sure howt to implement that

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `<int-sftp:outbound-gateway>` with `MGET` command:

> The message payload resulting from an `mget` operation is a `List<File>` object - a List of File objects, each representing a retrieved file.
>
> The remote directory is provided in the `file_remoteDirectory` header, and the pattern for the filenames is provided in the `file_remoteFile` header.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.12.RELEASE/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-outbound-gateway

In Java DSL it looks like:

```
.handle(Sftp.outboundGateway(sessionFactory(), AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Command.MGET,
                        "payload")
                        .options(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Option.RECURSIVE)
                        .regexFileNameFilter("(subSftpSource|.*1.txt)")
                        .localDirectoryExpression("'" + getTargetLocalDirectoryName() + "' + #remoteDirectory")
                        .localFilenameExpression("#remoteFileName.replaceFirst('sftpSource', 'localTarget')"))
```

where the `payload` is a SpEL expression for remote directory evaluation. In this case it is just really a payload of request message:

```
String dir = "sftpSource/";
registration.getInputChannel().send(new GenericMessage<>(dir + "*"));
```

If your remote directory is static and isn't changed from the Batch, you can use it as `LiteralExpression` - `expresion="'myRemoteDir'"` in the XML definition.

Since the result of this MGET command is a `List<File>` you should consider to use `Splitter` as the next step.

Comment: Hi @Gary, I've try outbound-gateway with mget command on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46707544/how-to-use-sftp-outbound-gateway-mget-command-to-download-files) , I want to use java config but I still facing some issue, I've read the docs and github example, but I still cannot work it out, can u kindly give some mget exampe with java configuration ? TIA