# how to use SFTP Outbound Gateway 'mget' command to download files?

Tags: spring-integration

I want to use the 'mget' command to download files from sftp server. here's my java config:

```
    @Bean
public SessionFactory<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> sftpSessionFactory() {
    DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory(true);
    ....
    return new CachingSessionFactory<>(factory);
}



@Bean(name = "lsGateway")
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "sftpChannel")
public MessageHandler handlerLs() {
    // call 'mget' command to download all the files in server folder
    SftpOutboundGateway sftpOutboundGateway = new  SftpOutboundGateway(sftpSessionFactory(), "mget", "payload");
    sftpOutboundGateway.setLocalDirectory(new File("/local/path"));
    return sftpOutboundGateway;

}
```

gateway interface:

```
@MessagingGateway
public interface OutboundGatewayOption {
@Gateway(requestChannel = "sftpChannel")
 List<File> mget(String dir);

}
```

execute download:

```
@Component
public class Step1Tasklet implements Tasklet {

@Autowired
private OutboundGatewayOption gatewayOption;

@Override
public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution stepContribution,
        ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {

    // download  files in server folder
    List<File> files = gatewayOption.mget("/ftp/server/path/");


    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
}
```

}

I got this exception :

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'sftpChannel' available
```

I've google around but cannot found the issue ,is anyone kindly help please!

Answer (score 0):

> No bean named 'sftpChannel'

Means you don't have `sftpChannel` `MessageChannel` bean yet.

I think the problem comes from the `@MessagingGateway` bean definition.

What you need to do is just declare that `sftpChannel` bean:

```
@Bean
public MessageChannel sftpChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}
```

Right, in the newest Spring Integration this problem has been fixed and `MessageChannel` is resolved from its name lately on demand.

Comment: Hi @Artem, I added the `    @Bean(name = "sftpChannel")
    public MessageChannel sftpChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }`  but it still : No bean named 'sftpChannel'

Comment: my spring-integration-sftp version 5.0.5

Comment: Well, there is no such a version. I guess it might be `4.0.5`. Consider to upgrade to the latest though: https://projects.spring.io/spring-integration/. Also, please, share more stack trace about the error. And stupid question: do you really have `@EnableIntegration` ?